# How do I view a hidden command window (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, scheduled-tasks

So for full context I've set up a Task Scheduler process to run a local Minecraft server as soon as the PC boots up, but it's running in the background and I want to be able to view the command window when I need to. The task is shown below and the user is my admin account and the only user on the PC. The batch file runs a .jar file which usually opens into a windows cmd window, but using the task scheduler it's not visible at all (the file is definitely running). any tips on how to open and use the cmd window for this running file?

[image]

Comment: Try to run the JAR with `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`.

Comment: How would I do that? currently the batch file looks like this

cd C:\Users\---\OneDrive\Documents\Minecraft server
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar server.jar nogui
CONSOLESTATE /Show
pause

Comment: Try to replace the `java.exe` with `javaw.exe` in that command, any change?

Comment: java.exe -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar server.jar nogui does the same as always and javaw.exe -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar server.jar nogui just doesn't work. when run manually as usual the window comes up (same as always). for javaw it simply tells me to press any key to continue and closes. when run from task scheduler it does nothing visible

Comment: it may be worth noting that if I switch to 'run only when user is logged on' I can see the window immediately as the file is run, but that isnt until I have logged in and the desktop has loaded which isnt what I need

Comment: I guess when you choose the option "Run if user is logged on or not" the task actually runs by the system account which doesn't have a graphical interface thus you can not see..